# Modification of Manhattan Geometry

Tags: metric-spaces, computer-science, coordinate-systems, machine-learning

In a gridworld, the usual metric used is the Manhattan Metric. From a given coordinate, there are only four possible directions: up, down, left, right.

I want to modify the metric by giving four more possible directions (totaling eight): usual 4 directions, northwest, northeast, southwest, southeast.

I want to ask if there is a name to this kind of modification. This is usually found in Artificial intelligence and machine learning.

Comment: I don't know the name, but it certainly looks like an interesting form of geometry.

Comment: What is the distance between two points separated by a NE move?

Comment: In Manhattan geometry, the only legal moves are east, west, north, south. So if you are in a Euclidean plane, at a point (0,0) and you want to go to the point (1,1), you have to go right (1,0) and up to (1,1). Alternatively you can go up (0,1) and right (1,1). Therefore, the least distance between (0,0) and (1,1) is 2 units. (As opposed to Euclidean distance of $\sqrt{2}$.)

Comment: Yes but in the suggested geometry? Is it one?

Comment: So in the modification that I want to have (allowing northeast, northwest, southeast, southwest moves), the least distance from (0,0) to (1,1) would be just 1. I'm not sure if it is legal, or this kind of thinking exists.

Comment: So you can imagine a standard tic-tac-toe grid (3x3). Start at the center, all the 'surrounding' spaces are 1 unit away from the center. I am hoping to create a sound mathematical definition for this in terms of direction/distance. But I want to know if something like this exists already.

Comment: When I wrote down that this may be an interesting form of geometry, I was exactly about that distance formula. Going slanted to the next point is a different distance than going horizontal or vertical. That poses some problem here for which I honestly have no answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are allowed to take steps in any of the eight directions you describe, the number of steps it takes to get from $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(x_2,y_2)$ is the maximum of $|x_1-x_2|$ and $|y_1-y_2|$. This is often called the [$L^\infty$ metric.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L-Infinity-Norm.html)

Comment: Well, I did not know that...

Comment: I searched it, also called Chebyshev distance. YES! Thank you!